# Program to find greatest divisors returns 0

Tags: c++

I just recently figured I'd try to learn how to code. I'm at the basics and found some exercises to do online, but I've sat at this for ~40 mins and can't figure it out. So even though this might seem basic to most of you I'll ask for some help :)

So here's the task:

The specified integers are in the range [m, n]. Write a program to find the number with the greatest divisors.

Input / output :

```
Initial data |   Result

10 40        |        36
```

Code :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int m, n, s, sd = 0, ats;
    double a = 0;
    ifstream fd("Duomenys.txt");
    fd >> m >> n;
    for(int i = m; i<=n; i++){
        s = 0;
        for(int j = 1; j<=i; ++j){
            a = 0;
            a = i % j;
            if(a = 0) s= s + 1; 
        }
    if(s > sd) {
        i = ats;
        s = sd;

        }
    }
    cout << ats;
        system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now I'm only using `cout << ats` to test it for the moment, but if I run it it gets a 0 as an answer.

Comment: Hint: `if(a = 0)` is probably not doing what you want

Comment: How so? Could you explain? :(

Comment: To compare values you should use `==` instead of `=` (which is used only to assign values). Also variable `ats` is never initialized (my compiler warns about that, and also I get a warning when I run the code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test whether a is equal to 0 or not, you have to use the **Equal to** operator, which is `==`.

With `if (a = 0)`, you're actually assigning 0 to a and then testing the result of this operation, which will always be 0. That's why the instructions of the if, here `s = s + 1;` will never be executed.

Other problems in your code:

- You use the variable `ats` but never initialize it, so its value is undetermined
- I don't see any reason why `a` is a `double` instead of an `int`

I suggest you to turn on all your compiler warnings and to start with [a good book or tutorial about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Figured it all out now! And it was a double because i was trying something difrent at the start :P Anyways thanks alot for taking the time to help me out!